# Соединение блоков линиями (как в Access связь таблиц 1 к 1)

Tags: виджет, mvc, qt, c++

Всем привет.
Как можно реализовать интерактивное соединение блоков с помощью линий.
Например есть два блока в виде квадрата, хочется интерактивно соединить, как в Access, таблиц.
Если вопрос некорректный, переспрашивайте.

**Редактор QT SDK Creator**

[Пример на Access](http://images.yandex.ru/yandsearch?p=2&text=%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%20access&pos=62&rpt=simage&img_url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp-informatika.ru%2Fpics%2Fz_id20_1.JPG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваши входные данные:

1. список блоков (напр. `struct Block`) с известными координатами узловых точек;
2. список соединительных линий (напр. `struct Connection`), содержащих координаты узловых точек (или `ID` соединяемых блоков)

При перемещении блоков перерисовываете соединительные линии.

P.S. В `Qt` есть пример `graphicsview/diagramscene`

Comment: struct Connection не нашел..

Comment: Так ее и нет - я для примера написал. Смысл был в том, что есть массив структур.

Comment: graphicsview/diagramscene - нашел пример. Ответ принят.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется что это возможно сделать при помощи WINAPI (если у вас ОС windows), там есть такие функции как LineTo и MoveTo они рисуют линии в любом месте формы, можно стрелки рисовать.

--------------------пример----------------------------

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void starline(int x0, int y0, int r, HDC hdc){
    int x, y;
    int a;
    int r1;

#define RTOR 2.5

    a = 18;
    r1 = r / RTOR;
    x = x0 + r * cos(a * 2 * 3.14 / 360);
    y = y0 - r * sin(a * 2 * 3.14 / 360);

    MoveToEx(hdc, x, y, NULL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        a = a + 36;

        x = x0 + r1 * cos(a * 2 * 3.14 / 360);
      y = y0 - r1 * sin(a * 2 * 3.14 / 360);

        LineTo(hdc, x, y);

        a = a + 36;

        if (a > 360) a = 18;

        x = x0 + r * cos(a * 2 * 3.14 / 360);
      y = y0 - r * sin(a * 2 * 3.14 / 360);

        LineTo(hdc, x, y);
    }
}

int main(){
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
// Получаем DC для рисования
HDC hDC = GetDC (hWnd);

// Получаем размер клиентской области окна
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);

// Создаем Pen
HPEN hPen = CreatePen (PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0));

// Выбираем свой Pen в DC, запоминаем старый Pen
HPEN hOldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject (hDC, hPen);

 starline(200, 200, 50, hDC);
/* 
// Перемещаем точку рисования в левый верхний угол окна
MoveToEx(hDC, rc.left, rc.top, NULL);
// Рисуем линию в правый нижний угол
LineTo(hDC, rc.right, rc.bottom);
*/

// Выбираем старый Pen в DC (освобождаем свой Pen из DC)
SelectObject(hDC, hOldPen);

// Удаляем Pen
DeleteObject (hPen);

// Освобождаем DC
ReleaseDC (hWnd, hDC);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: мне надо на Qt SDK

Comment: а какая у вас ОС?

Comment: windows 7 64

Comment: добавил пример как можно рисовать линии, посмотри все таки в сторону WINAPI (можно использовать вместе с QT)

Comment: спасибо, но мне надо на QT. Примеры почти нашел

Answer (score 1):

Есть пример - программа Database Browser, в ней этот принцип (QBE) реализован. Она Freeware хостится [тут](http://www.etl-tools.com/database-editors/database-browser/download.html). Может общение с [авторами](mailto:info@etl-tools.com) прояснит ситуацию.

Comment: спасибо, но мне надо другое, не связанное с БД, QBE и все такое. А надо блоки соединить, просто так навел с одного на другой и хоппа соединились.